# Rails: Has_many through query depending on the through table attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Having some problems with a has_many through query.

Using the example here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

The Appointment table has a column named **appointment_date**

How would I get all the Patients from a Specific Physician that have an appointment on a given date?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Patient.includes(:physicians, :appointments).where('physicians.id = ? AND appointments.appointment_date = ?', <id or ids array>, Date.today)
```

Where Date.today could be changed with anything and the pysician is specified by an id or an array of ids.

You could also do:

```
physician = Physician.find(id)
patients = physician.patients.includes(:appointments).where('appointments.appointment_date  = ?', some_date)
```

Edit:

In Rails 4 and forward, you need to add `references(:appointments)` to the query in order to use appointments in the where clause.

Comment: this didn't work for me on rails 4, I spent quite a bit of time searching and found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799934/has-many-through-how-do-you-access-join-table-attributes) for rails 4:

Comment: Yup, in rails 4 you need to use `references` to reference table names from includes.