# has_many :through : How do you access join table attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models in Rails 4 with a simple has_many :through association:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_options
  has_many :options, through: :model_options
end

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_options
  has_many :models, through: :model_options
end

class ModelOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
  belongs_to :option
end
```

I want to be able to iterate over a Model instance's Options:

```
  model = Model.find.first
  model.options.each {}
```

and access the attributes on the join table.

In Rails 3 you could do this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_options
  has_many :options, through: :model_options , select: 'options.*, model_options.*'
end
```

But select: is deprecated and this produces a deprecation warning.

That said, the SQL generated contains the link table data:

```
SELECT options.*, model_options.* FROM "options"
INNER JOIN "model_options" ON "options"."id" = "model_options"."option_id"
WHERE "model_options"."model_id" = $1 ORDER BY "options".name ASC  [["model_id", 1]]
```

But the collection returned by AR from model.options removes the link table data.

To remove the deprecations warning in Rails 4, and still produce the same SQL, I did this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_options
  has_many :options, -> { select('options.*, model_options.*') }, through: :model_options
end
```

So, the query is correct, but I am struggling to find the correct way to access the link table data.

I have tried various ways:

```
 model options
 model.options.joins(:model_options)
 model.options.select('options.*, model_options.*')
 model.model_options.joins(:option)
 ...
```

None include the join table data.

Thanks.

Comment: Does ModelOption model do anything more outside of two ids?

Comment: Yes, ModelOption has a number of attributes on it. For example, price, where an option's price will vary depending on the model.

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: @Karsten, I've found out that join table attributes are transparently accessible as `model.price` (where `price` as the attribute of _ModelOption_) after you've specified the `has_many ... select()` statement to include them.

Answer (score 33):

The answer may be different regarding what you want to achieve. Do you want to retrieve those attributes or to use them for querying ?

### Loading results

ActiveRecord is about mapping table rows to objects, so you can't have attributes from one object into an other.

Let use a more concrete example : There are House, Person and Dog. A person belongs_to house. A dog  belongs_to a person. A house has many people. A house has many dogs through people.

Now, if you have to retrieve a dog, you don't expect to have person attributes in it. It wouldn't make sense to have a car_id attribute in dog attributes.

That being said, it's not a problem : what you really want, I think, is to avoid making a lot of db queries, here. Rails has your back on that :

```
# this will generate a sql query, retrieving options and model_options rows
options = model.options.includes( :model_options )

# no new sql query here, all data is already loaded
option = options.first

# still no new query, everything is already loaded by `#includes`
additional_data = option.model_options.first
```

Edit : It will behaves like this in console. In actually app code, the sql query will be fired on second command, because first one didn't use the result (the sql query is triggered only when we need its results). But this does not change anything here : it's only fired a single time.

`#includes` does just that : loading all attributes from a foreign table in the result set. Then, everything is mapped to have a meaningful object oriented representation.

### Using attributes in query

If you want to make query based on both Options and ModelOptions, you'll have to use `#references`. Let say your ModelOption has an `active` attribute :

```
# This will return all Option related to model 
# for which ModelOption is active
model.options.references( :model_options ).where( model_options: { active: true })
```

### Conclusion

`#includes` will load all foreign rows in result set so that you can use them later without further querying the database. `#references` will also allow you to use the table in queries.

In no case will you have an object containing data from an other model, but that's a good thing.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't what I see. Here is result when I run:

`options = model.options.includes(:model_options)`

Then options.to_sql:

`=> "SELECT "options".* FROM "options"
    INNER JOIN "model_options" ON "options"."id" = "model_options"."option_id"
    WHERE "model_options"."model_id" = $1 ORDER BY "options".name ASC"`

So, it's not returning the model_options attributes.

Note, however, that I can do, say: `model.options.where(model_options: {price: 10})`

and it returns the appropriate option. But still AR does not return the model_options data.

Comment: That's probably because rails decided it will have better performances here to do two queries. You should not trust what `#to_sql` shows, because it will only show first query if there are several. To see what is indeed run, fire the query in `rails console`.

Comment: Yes, I fired the query. The resultset does not contain the link table attributes. The SQL I posted above are the queries executed from doing so. Just to be clear, this is not a problem in Rails 3. It's new, at least to me, in Rails 4.

Comment: Actually there are cases in which you want to combine the attributes of one thing "into" another.  For example `user` `has_many :folders, through: :folder_permissions` and `folder` `has_many :users, through :folder_permissions`.  One expects folder permissions to be an attribute of a folder, but in a habtm association it makes most sense to store those permissions in the join model.  I'd like to know how to do this in rails 4 also.

Comment: Do you know how I could use a scope defined in the join table?
Because if I use `<user>.items.custom_scope.references(:join_table)` it will try to execute custom_scope on top of `Item::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`.

Comment: This does not access attributes on the through table.

Comment: This answer is technically incorrect; I posted an answer below explaining how you can access the join model attributes without any N+1 queries.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is actually quite simple, and OP had it right on his question.

If `ModelOption` has a column named `name` and you want it to be accessible in the `Model`
s `Option` instances, you simply do:

```rb
model.options.select('options.*, model_options.*').each do |model|
  puts model.name
end
```

The way this works is because Rails is going to automatically issue a JOIN from `Option` to `ModelOption` when you call `model.options`, so all their columns are already "merged" by SQL in a single line. Then the `.select` call on that relation will make them available in the resulting instances.

Notice, however, that you are selecting ALL attributes `(*)` from the join model this way, and you are going to have ambiguity in many fields (like `id, created_at, updated_at`, and so on.

So, the way to go is being explicit about the columns of the joined models that you want to select, for instance:

```rb
model.options.select('options.*, model_options.name').each do |model|
  puts model.name
end
```

Lastly, if both your `Model` and `ModelOption` models had a column named #name, you could rename one of them to eliminate the ambiguity like this:

```rb
model.options.select('options.*, model_options.name as model_option_name').each do |model|
  puts model.name # will get you Model#name
  puts model.model_option_name # will get you ModelOption#name
end
```

Lastly, if you are always going to use this data from the join model, you can even declare this in the association itself, like so:

```rb
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :model_options
  has_many :options, -> { distinct.select("options.*, model_options.name") }, through: :model_options
end

# And then you can:

model.options.each do |option|
  puts option.name # this will get you ModelOption#name
end
```

As you can see, the most upvoted answer is incorrect, because it states that `you can't have attributes from one object into an other`, and you can clearly do that with Rails.

Answer (score 3):

Just like Olivier said you have to eager load the association.

For some reason the association is not returning the single model_options data when you use **includes**.

It works for me when i force AR to do a single query with **eager_load**.

```
options = model.options.eager_load( :model_options )

# then
data = options.first.model_options.first
```

Answer (score 2):

your edit your model :

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_options
  has_many :options, through: :model_options

  def all_options 
        model_options + options
  end

end
```

Now can access all atribute from joining ("model_options") table and "options" table, like this:

001 >>model = Model.first

002 >>model.all_options

More: https://blog.codedge.io/rails-join-table-with-extra-attributes/