# has_many thorugh need properties of through class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models:

```
User id, name, ...
  has_many :user_books
  has_many :books, through: :user_books

Books id, name, author 
  has_many :user_books

UserBooks id, user_id, book_id, has_read, rating
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
```

Okay so this is the setting. When I do User.books, I get a collection of books, but can't access the properties(book.name,book.author) that are set in UserBooks such as has_read, rating etc.

How do I read both the Books and UserBooks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799934/has-many-through-how-do-you-access-join-table-attributes

Comment: that one doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use the join model, to do something like the following. In the controller:

```
@user_books = @user.user_books.includes(:books)
```

(Using the includes prevents the `n+1 queries` issue because it caches the books needed by the user_books, resulting in 2 total queries)

Then in the view, you can do things like this:

```
<%= @user_books.each do |user_book| %>
  <div class="<%= 'read' if user_book.has_read? %>">
    <h2><%= user_book.book.name %> <small>by <%= user_book.book.author %></h2>
    <span><%= user_book.rating %></span>
  </div>
<%= end %>
```

If you'd like to include the book's methods you could use `delegate` like so:

```
class UserBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book

  delegate :has_read, to: :book
  delegate :author, to: :book
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

Then you could do the following:

```
@books = @user.user_books.includes(:books)
```

Then in view:

```
<%= @books.each do |book| %>
  <div class="<%= 'read' if book.has_read? %>">
    <h2><%= book.name %> <small>by <%= book.author %></h2>
    <span><%= book.rating %></span>
  </div>
<%= end %>
```

Now UNDERSTAND that although we call it "Book" in the controller and view, it's a "UserBook" object.

Comment: i actually wanted properties of user_books along with book in the same variable so I could do book.name and book.has_read with using user_book.book.has_read. How can I create a new object with properties from two different objects