# Access attribute in Active Record 'through' association object

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have two classes, `User` and `Product` in a 'many-to-many through' association, using the class `Prole` (for product role).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :proles
  has_many :products, through: :proles
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :proles
  has_many :users, through: :proles
end

class Prole < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has an attribute called 'role'
end
```

prole has an attribute called `role` which I'd like to use to qualify the user-product association.

The association works fine, but I can't figure out how to access the `role` attribute after creating the association. For example, if I do:

```
user.products << product
```

how can I access the attribute in the prole object just created?

I guess I could iterate through the prole objects and find the correct one, but I'm hoping there's a cleaner way.

Is this possible? Any hints?

TIA.

I was hoping for something a little more direct, but here's a 
POSSIBLE ANSWER:

```
prole = Prole.find_by user_id: user.id, product_id: product.id
```

or even better

```
prole = user.proles.where("product_id = #{product.id}")
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear "from where" you would like to access `role` attribute. Could you provide some pseudo-code of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried that didn't work?

Comment: Okay, I've edited to make my question clearer, I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, it looks like the easiest way to grab specifically the Prole object that was just created is by querying by the two foreign keys directly against the Prole model, as suggested in your possible answer.

```
Prole.find_by(user_id: user.id, product_id: product.id)
```

If you want it as an association on the `user` object, you could use the `includes` approach to do eager loading, but it will still load every `prole` for the `user` in question

```
# specifying proles: {product_id: product.id} in the where clause here 
# only limits users retrieved, not proles
user = User.includes(:proles).where(id: user.id) 
# eager-loaded prole array
user.proles.find { |prole| prole.product_id == product.id }
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18800846/4280232) for more info on that. But it looks like your possible answer is the cleanest way.

Comment: That didn't work for me, but it did give me an idea which I've added to my question as POSSIBLE ANSWER.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer since it put me on the track of a useful solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you're right, it looks like if you're after the `Prole` object you're going to have to start from that model and query from there, otherwise you'll have to iterate through an association.