# Access has_many :through with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, where-clause, has-many-through

I have  model BatchClass and  SubjectTeacherBatchClass having attribues like below.

```
class SubjectTeacherBatchClass < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :batch_class
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :shift
  belongs_to :session_batch
end
```

and

```
class BatchClass < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :subject_teacher_batch_classes
  has_many :subjects, through: :subject_teacher_batch_classes
  has_many :teachers, source: :user, foreign_key: 'user_id', through: :subject_teacher_batch_classes
end
```

I want to access batch_class.teachers but with custom attributes like i.e.

```
batch_class.teachers.where(session_batch_id: session_batch.id, shift_id: current_shift.id)
```

The problem is that `session_batch_id` and `shift_id` are not attributes of `User` class (alias teacher) but are attributes of `SubjectTeacherBatchClass` class. (the through class)

Is there any better way to get teachers from batch_class passing those default attributes (session_batch and shift)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [https://stackoverflow.com/q/18799934/1154044](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799934/has-many-through-how-do-you-access-join-table-attributes) question rather similar to yours.

According to your models, you can try this query

```
batch_class.teachers.
  references(:subject_teacher_batch_classes).
  where(subject_teacher_batch_classes: {
    session_batch_id: session_batch.id, shift_id: current_shift.id
  })
```

Comment: the `references` is not actually necessary in this case because the join is required to get from `batch_class` to `teachers` (e.g. `through`)

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you for your comment, I'll try to reproduce it soon by hands.