# ActiveRecord query building

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm a bit stuck trying to build what seems like a rather complex query and hope somebody can point me at the right direction.

Model `Project` has 2 has_many through relationships to model `Sector` and model `Service`.

what i want to achieve is something like:

```
/projects?service_ids[]=1&sector_ids[]=1&sector_ids[]=2
```

where essentially i want to get only the projects which have service 1 and sectors 1 and 2, for example.

I know that due to the has_many through relationship, i can get the projects under a service or sector. But to do that i need to first fetch a service/sector. In this case however, i feel i need to get projects and filter based on the relationships. I'm just not sure how i'd go about doing that.

I hope i managed to explain it properly. Do let me know if you need any extra info.

EDIT:

To clarify a bit, if no service_ids is passed on params, than i want to check the sector_ids. now, if both sector_ids and service_ids are passed, i need to filter all the projects to get ONLY the projects that have a relationship to both the services with passed ids and sectors with passed ids.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you want query to get specific service 1 and sector 1 and 2 or it can change based on parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails has\_many through query depending on the through table attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641504/rails-has-many-through-query-depending-on-the-through-table-attribute)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. As you can see, on the question, they ask to get all Patients from a specific Physician. In my case, i need to get all projects that have on their relationship the ids passed in the params.

Comment: Will this work for you - Project.include(:services, :sectors).where("services.id = ? and sectors.id in (?)", service_id, sectors_id)

Comment: got this: wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module). Not sure what it means :/

Comment: I guess the error is because i'm meant to use 'includes' and not 'include'?

Comment: Can you try this - Project.joins(:services, :sectors).where("services.id = ? and sectors.id in (?)", service_id, sectors_id) . Here sectors_id can be array of values for different sectors

Comment: This might have worked for my purpose with a little change. Project.joins(:services, :sectors).where("services.id in (?) and sectors.id in (?)", params[:service_ids], params[:sector_ids]). I'm just testing it now but its looking good. Send this as an answer and i'll mark it as the right answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Great! Have posted it as an answer with the correct version :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below query to get details from both services and sectors table

```
Project.joins(:services, :sectors).where("services.id in (?) and sectors.id in (?)", params[:service_ids], params[:sector_ids])
```